# JQuery class add/remove not working (unknown delegation to use)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session, delegation

I am running Javascript/Jquery inside a php code. What it should do is when someone goes onto the page, the session is checked (If there is a session, they have logged in), and if there is a session, it turn the login button into a logout button by changing the class. I have read that you need a delegation, but I am not sure what to put to check for a session. Here is the session check/run Jquery script:

```
 <?php

if (isset($_SESSION['mysession']) && $_SESSION['mysession'] == true) {
 echo  "<script type='text/javascript'> $('.btna').addClass('.btnh');
         $('.btna').removeClass('.btna');</script>";
}
        ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
//html code
```

The "btna" and "btnf" classes are the buttons. "btna" is the login, "btnf" is the logout.
Here is the code for the logout button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btnh" placeholder="Logout">
        Logout
    </button>
</body>
```

I have not linked my button to the logout form yet.
The problem is even when my session is set, the login button does not change class into the logout button.
**So simply, what delegation would I use in my JQuery to check for sessions, and/or is my JQuery code correct (in terms of semicolons, apostrophes, etc.)?** Thanks

EDIT: Unfortunately it seems that so far none of these answers have succeeded so far - but thank you guys so much for the help. However, I think the problem lies elsewhere to what I am asking. It must be in the HTML code for the logout button, or somewhere in CSS. I will keep looking, however if you guys do have a suggestion, please post it.

EDIT 2: If it makes any difference, my logout button is on another page, but linked with CSS. Here is some new PHP code I made, can anyone see why it is not working (It does not show up at all). This is in the body section of my homepage.

```
<?php

    if (isset($_SESSION['flinders']) && $_SESSION['flinders'] == true) {
        echo '<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btna" placeholder="Login">';
        echo                    'Login';
        echo                '</button>';
    }
        else{
            echo '<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btnh" placeholder="Logout">';
            echo                'Logout';
            echo            '</button>';
        }
?>
```

Comment: there are multiple errors as i saw in first read.

Comment: addClass without the point of the class.

Comment: why do you need to use jquery for this? just switch the classes based on your `$_SESSION` variable with php

Comment: @billyonecan could you please elaborate? I have been trying to do this with just php but I had no success, so I switched to javascript, and then to JQuery.

Comment: Just add the condition in your markup, eg. `<button class="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['mysession']) && $_SESSION['mysession'] == true) ? 'btnh' : 'btna'; ?>">`

Answer (score 5):

In JQuery statement, do not use dot(.) for class.

```
before : $('.btna').addClass('.btnh');
after  : $('.btna').addClass('btnh');
```

Good luck.

Comment: So if you don't need a dot for classes, why do you have a dot in ('.btna')?

Comment: @PlanetAlexander dot is only used in CSS Indicator. First ('.btna') is used for CSS Indicator.

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
echo  "<script type='text/javascript'> $('.btna').addClass('.btnh');
         $('.btna').removeClass('.btna');</script>";
```

To

```
echo  "<script type='text/javascript'> $('.btna').addClass('btnh');
         $('.btna').removeClass('btna');</script>";
```

You don't need to add a dot before the class name

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
$('.btna').addClass('btnh');
$('.btna').removeClass('btna');
</script>
```

This should work. If not, use this to be sure that the DOM is ready :

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('.btna').addClass('btnh');
        $('.btna').removeClass('btna');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var sessvalue='<?php echo $_SESSION['mysession']; ?>';
if(sessvalue == true) {
        $('.btna').addClass('btnh');
        $('.btna').removeClass('btna');
}

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use JavaScript for this at all. Just add a condition to set the class using PHP.

```
<?php

$btnClass = (isset($_SESSION['mysession']) && $_SESSION['mysession'] == true) 
          ? 'btnh' // value if above condition evaluates true
          : 'btna'; // value if above condition evaluates false

?>

<button type="submit" name="submit" class="<?php echo $btnClass; ?>">
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, DOM is not ready when you're running your script. Wait for ready event before run it:

```
$( function() {
    //your code here
} )
```